# DrawMapRect called multiple times on a custom MKOverlayView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Anyone ever resolved this issue here [iOS - MKOverlayView custom view rect fills works, but line draws do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023904/ios-mkoverlayview-custom-view-rect-fills-works-but-line-draws-do-not?answertab=active#tab-top)?

I am stuck with the same problem. The canDrawMapRect is called only once and returns YES . Butthe drawMapRect method is called twice with the same MKMapRect and MKZoomScale. My custom `MKOverlay` layer was only added programatically to the `MKMapview`.

Thanks